# How to supply parameters to a function/constructor that may not always exist?

Tags: java

I have created my custom Optional annotation like this

```
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.FIELD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.PARAMETER;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR;

import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;


import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({FIELD,PARAMETER,METHOD,CONSTRUCTOR})
public @interface Optional {
    String id() default "";
}
```

In my class I have used it like:

```
public class A extends BaseClassA {

    @Optional
    private String id;
    public A(@Optional final String id) {
        this.id=id;
    }
}
```

Basically I don't always have a value for this parameter. There are other fields in the class which I have omitted in this example to keep it simple.

In my test I want to instantiate like this

```
A anObject = new A("1000") //example of when Id exists
A anObject = new A() // example of when Id doesn't exist.
```

How can I use this optional annotation to create objects with/without supplying the id attribute ?

Comment: you'll have to define an additional constructor. That's required by the java language.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing would be to define two constructors. One that takes the id parameter and one with no parameters.

Like:

```
public class A extends BaseClassA {

    @Optional
    private String id;
    public A(@Optional final String id) {
        this.id=id;
    }
    public A() {
        // do nothing...
    }
}
```

Unless you mean to have several (optional) parameters and do not wish to write many constructors...

Comment: When do you specify @optional in constructor and the private field ? Is it necessary in this case to specify in both ?

Comment: I defined a constructor like that, I want that when I don't pass anything the default value set should be empty and not null, how do I do that using the custom annotation

Comment: Writing additional constructors (or even methods) is much simpler than writing a custom annotation. Did you ever wrote a custom annotation before? Unless you plan to use this on many classes, just write multiple constructors. Will be much simpler and faster (to write).

Answer (score 0):

In actuality, the custom annotation doesn't buy you much.  If you want to have a default value for a specific constructor, then specify a no-arg constructor which passes the default arguments directly instead.

```
public class A extends BaseClassA {
    private String id;

    public A(final String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public A() {
        this("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to take a look at [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/), in special [Constructor annotations](http://projectlombok.org/features/Constructor.html). No need to roll your own.

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor   
public class A extends BaseClassA {

    private String id;

}
```

Will generate both an empty constructor (since `id` is not `final` or has been annotated with `@NonNull`) and a constructor with `id` (to satisfy `@AllArgsConstructor`)

Generated:

```
public class A extends BaseClassA {

    private String id;

    public A() {
    }

    @java.beans.ConstructorProperties({"id"})
    public A(String id) {
       this.id = id;
    }

}
```